# Java CardLayout does not change Panel until unrelated loop is finished

Tags: java, panel, cardlayout

I created application which uses multiple panels, so I have chosen cardLayout. The thing is, when the following code gets executed, in the UserInterface method SinglePlayer() something weird happens. I use commands *frame.add(fieldPanel, "card2");* and *cardLayout.show(frame, "card2");* but when that code gets executed, my whole window gets black instead of showing fieldPanel. Only when the while loop (which is located just under those lines) is finished, fieldPanel is shown.
What could be the problem?

Here is the code:

UserInterface class:

```
    package view;

import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import model.Field;
import model.Food;
import model.Snake;
import model.Snake.SnakePoint;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;


public class UserInterface extends JFrame{
private JLabel singlePlayer,multiPlayer,quit;
private Container menu;
public JPanel introPanel,fieldPanel;
public CardLayout cardLayout;

private Field field;
private Snake snake1,snake2;
private Food food;

JPanel frame;

Thread mainThread;


public UserInterface(){

    cardLayout=new CardLayout();
    frame=new JPanel(cardLayout);

    // Adjust window
    introPanel=new JPanel(new MigLayout());
    setSize(740, 515);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(true);
    setTitle("Snake");
    setVisible(true);

    // Instantiate buttons
    singlePlayer=new JLabel();
    multiPlayer=new JLabel();
    quit=new JLabel();
    singlePlayer.setIcon(new ImageIcon("files/singleplayer.jpg"));
    multiPlayer.setIcon(new ImageIcon("files/multiplayer.jpg"));
    quit.setIcon(new ImageIcon("files/quit.jpg"));
    quit.addMouseListener(new Mouse());
    singlePlayer.addMouseListener(new Mouse());
    multiPlayer.addMouseListener(new Mouse());

    // Create menu panel
    menu=new JPanel(new MigLayout());
    menu.add(singlePlayer,"cell 0 0");
    menu.add(multiPlayer,"cell 0 1");
    menu.add(quit,"cell 0 2");

    // Insert menu to the center    
    introPanel.add(menu,"push, align center");

    // Create card layout
    frame.add(introPanel,"card1");
    add(frame);
}

public void singlePlayer(){
    field=new Field(false);
    snake1=new Snake();
    food=new Food();



    fieldPanel=field.getFieldPanel();
    frame.add(fieldPanel, "card2");
    cardLayout.show(frame, "card2");

    revalidate();
    repaint();

    for(int i=0; i<field.FIELD_WIDTH;i++){
        for(int j=0; j<field.FIELD_HEIGHT;j++){
            this.addKeyListener(new KListener());

        }
    }

    while(!snake1.isBodyHit()){
        revalidate();
        repaint();
        redrawField();
        redrawFood();
        redrawSnake();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Error in UserInterface run method");
        }

        if(snake1.head.positionX==field.foodX && snake1.head.positionY==field.foodY){
            snake1.increaseSnake();
            field.resetFood();
        }

        snake1.moveSnake();
        System.out.println(snake1.direction);
    }
}



private class Mouse implements MouseListener {

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==quit){
            System.exit(0);;
        } else if(e.getSource()==singlePlayer){
            singlePlayer();
        } else if(e.getSource()==multiPlayer){

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {


    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==singlePlayer){
            singlePlayer.setIcon(new ImageIcon("files/singlePlayer2.jpg"));
        } else if(e.getSource()==multiPlayer){
            multiPlayer.setIcon(new ImageIcon("files/multiPlayer2.jpg"));
        } else if(e.getSource()==quit){
            quit.setIcon(new ImageIcon("files/quit2.jpg"));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==singlePlayer){
            singlePlayer.setIcon(new ImageIcon("files/singlePlayer.jpg"));
        } else if(e.getSource()==multiPlayer){
            multiPlayer.setIcon(new ImageIcon("files/multiPlayer.jpg"));
        } else if(e.getSource()==quit){
            quit.setIcon(new ImageIcon("files/quit.jpg"));
        }

    }

}


public void redrawSnake(){
    SnakePoint temp=snake1.head;
    while(temp!=null){
        field.fieldLabels[temp.positionX][temp.positionY].setIcon(new ImageIcon("files/snake.jpg"));
        temp=temp.next;
    }
}

public void redrawField(){
    for(int i=0;i<field.FIELD_WIDTH;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<field.FIELD_HEIGHT;j++)
            field.fieldLabels[i][j].setIcon(new ImageIcon("files/field_gray.jpg"));
}

public void redrawFood(){
    for(int i=0;i<field.FIELD_WIDTH;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<field.FIELD_HEIGHT;j++)
            if( i== field.foodX && j==field.foodY)
                field.fieldLabels[i][j].setIcon(new ImageIcon("files/food.jpg"));
}

private class KListener implements KeyListener
{

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            snake1.direction='s';
        } else if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            snake1.direction='n';
        } else if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
            snake1.direction='e';
        } else if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            snake1.direction='w';
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

}

Snake class:
        package model;

```
public class Snake implements Runnable {
public SnakePoint head,tail;
private int length=0;
private static int numberOfSnakes=0;
private static final int initialLength=5;
public  char direction;

public int foodX,foodY;
private int score;

@Override
public void run() {
    numberOfSnakes++;

}

public SnakePoint getHead(){return head;}


public Snake(){

        head=new SnakePoint();
        int x=25,y=30;
        head.positionX=x;
        head.positionY=y;

        SnakePoint temp1=new SnakePoint();
        head.next=temp1;
        temp1.positionX=24;
        temp1.positionY=y;

        SnakePoint temp2=new SnakePoint();
        temp1.next=temp2;
        temp2.positionX=23;
        temp2.positionY=y;

        temp1=temp2;
        temp2=new SnakePoint();
        temp1.next=temp2;
        temp2.positionX=22;
        temp2.positionY=y;
        temp1=temp2;
        temp2=new SnakePoint();
        temp1.next=temp2;
        temp2.positionX=21;
        temp2.positionY=y;
        temp2.next=null;

        tail=temp2;
        direction='e';
        length=5;
}

public SnakePoint getPointAt(int position){
    SnakePoint temp=head;
    for(int i=0; ; i++)
    {
        if(position==i)
            break;
        temp=temp.next;
    }
    return temp;
}

public void moveSnake(){

    if(!(direction=='w' && head.positionX==0) && 
            !(direction=='e' && head.positionX==44) &&
            !(direction=='n' && head.positionY==0) && 
            !(direction=='s' && head.positionY==49)){
        if(direction=='e'){
            SnakePoint newHead=tail;
            SnakePoint oneBeforeTail=getPointAt(length-2);
            oneBeforeTail.next=null;
            tail=oneBeforeTail;
            newHead.positionX=head.positionX+1;
            newHead.positionY=head.positionY;
            newHead.next=head;
            head=newHead;
        } else if(direction=='w'){
            SnakePoint newHead=tail;
            SnakePoint oneBeforeTail=getPointAt(length-2);
            oneBeforeTail.next=null;
            tail=oneBeforeTail;
            newHead.positionX=head.positionX-1;
            newHead.positionY=head.positionY;
            newHead.next=head;
            head=newHead;

        } else if(direction=='s'){
            SnakePoint newHead=tail;
            SnakePoint oneBeforeTail=getPointAt(length-2);
            oneBeforeTail.next=null;
            tail=oneBeforeTail;
            newHead.positionX=head.positionX;
            newHead.positionY=head.positionY+1;
            newHead.next=head;
            head=newHead;
        } else if(direction=='n'){
            SnakePoint newHead=tail;
            SnakePoint oneBeforeTail=getPointAt(length-2);
            oneBeforeTail.next=null;
            tail=oneBeforeTail;
            newHead.positionX=head.positionX;
            newHead.positionY=head.positionY-1;
            newHead.next=head;
            head=newHead;
        }
    } else if(direction=='w' && head.positionX==0){
        SnakePoint newHead=tail;
        SnakePoint oneBeforeTail=getPointAt(length-2);
        oneBeforeTail.next=null;
        tail=oneBeforeTail;
        newHead.positionX=44;
        newHead.positionY=head.positionY;
        newHead.next=head;
        head=newHead;
    } else if(direction=='e' && head.positionX==44){
        SnakePoint newHead=tail;
        SnakePoint oneBeforeTail=getPointAt(length-2);
        oneBeforeTail.next=null;
        tail=oneBeforeTail;
        newHead.positionX=0;
        newHead.positionY=head.positionY;
        newHead.next=head;
        head=newHead;
    } else if(direction=='n' && head.positionY==0){
        SnakePoint newHead=tail;
        SnakePoint oneBeforeTail=getPointAt(length-2);
        oneBeforeTail.next=null;
        tail=oneBeforeTail;
        newHead.positionX=head.positionX;
        newHead.positionY=49;
        newHead.next=head;
        head=newHead;
    } else if(direction=='s' && head.positionY==49){
        SnakePoint newHead=tail;
        SnakePoint oneBeforeTail=getPointAt(length-2);
        oneBeforeTail.next=null;
        tail=oneBeforeTail;
        newHead.positionX=head.positionX;
        newHead.positionY=0;
        newHead.next=head;
        head=newHead;
    } 
}

public boolean isBodyHit(){
    SnakePoint temp=head.next;
    while(temp != null){
        if(head.positionX==temp.positionX && head.positionY==temp.positionY){
            System.out.println("here");
            return true;
        }

        temp=temp.next;
    }
    return false;
}

public void increaseSnake(){
    length++;
    SnakePoint newPoint=new SnakePoint();
    if(!(direction=='w' && head.positionX==0) && 
            !(direction=='e' && head.positionX==44) &&
            !(direction=='n' && head.positionY==0) && 
            !(direction=='s' && head.positionY==49)){
        if(direction=='w'){
            newPoint.positionX=head.positionX+1;
            newPoint.positionY=head.positionY;
            newPoint.next=head;
            head=newPoint;
        } else if(direction=='e'){
            newPoint.positionX=head.positionX-1;
            newPoint.positionY=head.positionY;
            newPoint.next=head;
            head=newPoint;
        } else if(direction=='s'){
            newPoint.positionX=head.positionX;
            newPoint.positionY=head.positionY+1;
            newPoint.next=head;
            head=newPoint;
        }else if(direction=='n'){
            newPoint.positionX=head.positionX;
            newPoint.positionY=head.positionY-1;
            newPoint.next=head;
            head=newPoint;
        }
    } else if(direction=='w' && head.positionX==0){
        newPoint.positionX=44;
        newPoint.positionY=head.positionY;
        newPoint.next=head;
        head=newPoint;
    } else if(direction=='e' && head.positionX==44){
        newPoint.positionX=0;
        newPoint.positionY=head.positionY;
        newPoint.next=head;
        head=newPoint;
    } else if(direction=='n' && head.positionY==0){
        newPoint.positionX=head.positionX;
        newPoint.positionY=49;
        newPoint.next=head;
        head=newPoint;
    } else if(direction=='s' && head.positionY==49){
        newPoint.positionX=head.positionX;
        newPoint.positionY=0;
        newPoint.next=head;
        head=newPoint;
    }
}

public int getLength(){ return length;}

public class SnakePoint{
    public int positionX,positionY;
    public SnakePoint next;

    public SnakePoint(){
        positionX=0;
        positionY=0;
        next=null;
    }

    public void addPoint(SnakePoint parent){

    }
}
```

}

field class:
        package model;

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class Field extends JFrame  {

private JPanel myFieldPanel;
private JPanel leftPanel;
private JPanel centralPanel;
private JPanel rightPanel;
private boolean isMultiPlayer;

private JLabel leftScore,rightScore;
private int score;


public int foodX,foodY;
public JLabel [][] fieldLabels;
public final int FIELD_WIDTH=45,FIELD_HEIGHT=50;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public JPanel getFieldPanel(){return myFieldPanel;}

public void resetFood(){
    // formula: new Random().nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
    foodX=new Random().nextInt(45 - 0 + 1) + 0;
    foodY=new Random().nextInt(49 - 0 + 1) + 0;
}


public Field(boolean type){
    myFieldPanel=new JPanel();
    this.isMultiPlayer=type;

    // Adjust playground and score tables
    leftPanel=new JPanel(new MigLayout());
    centralPanel=new JPanel(new MigLayout("gap 0, wrap 50"));
    centralPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.black));
    rightPanel=new JPanel(new MigLayout());

    // Set leftPanel
    score=0;
    leftScore=new JLabel("Player 1 score:\n"+score);
    leftPanel.add(leftScore, "dock north");

    // Adjust field and central panel
    fieldLabels=new JLabel[FIELD_WIDTH][FIELD_HEIGHT];
    for(int i=0;i<FIELD_WIDTH;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<FIELD_HEIGHT;j++){
            // Create each label
            fieldLabels[i][j]=new JLabel();

            // Paint each label
                fieldLabels[i][j].setIcon(new ImageIcon("files/field_gray.jpg"));

            // Add each label into layout
            centralPanel.add(fieldLabels[i][j]);

        }
    }

    // Adjust rightPanel
    rightPanel.add(new JLabel("Player 2 score: "),"dock north");

    // Final preparations
    myFieldPanel.setLayout(new MigLayout());
    myFieldPanel.add(leftPanel, "cell 0 0");
    myFieldPanel.add(centralPanel, "cell 1 0");
    myFieldPanel.add(rightPanel, "cell 2 0");
    resetFood();
}

public boolean IsMultiPlayer(){ return isMultiPlayer;}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read more about concurrency in Swing: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html

I strongly guess that the method `singlePlayer()` is executed in the Event Dispatching thread. The `while` loop containing `Thread.sleep(..)` method blocks updating the GUI which freezes the GUI (or draw it black).

You must ensure that all methods executed in the EDT return quick.

Comment: Actually, when I comment out Thread.sleep() part. nothing changes. The problem remains

Comment: Read the tutorial. Basic rules: Never block the EDT. All Swing and GUI things must run in the EDT.

Comment: I added another hint mentioning the while loop in singePlayer(). All EDT methods must return as quick as possible and must never block.

Comment: I appreciate your help. But I really do not understand that hint of yours. Could you please be more specific. Which method do you think of when you say that something blocks EDT?

Comment: singlePlayer() is executed in the EDT but as long as the while loop is running the EDT cannot update the GUI.

Comment: I tried to make the UserInterface class implement Runnable, and I moved the while loop into the run() method. In that case, the problem is solved, but I get the another problem. redrawSnake() method somehow does not redraw the snake properly. Sometimes it skips and does not color few spots of the snake. :S

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71716/discussion-between-uli-and-xpg94).

Comment: Problem solved using this message of yours."If you want to execute a GUI update from your non EDT thread use:
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
createAndShowGUI();
}
});"

Thanks mate :)